# How to convert JSON array into JSON object and write it into file using shell script?

Tags: arrays, json, shell, parsing, unix

I have the below format of JSON file which is having `issues[]` array and I tried to use it for Kibana. But unfortunately Kibana doesn't support nested objects and array and there is a plugin to utilize so that I need to downgrade which I can't do right now because in that case I will lose all my data.

**Sample data:**

```
{
    "expand": "schema,names",
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 50,
    "total": 4,
    "issues": [{
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id": "1999875",
            "self": "https://amazon.kindle.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/1999875",
            "key": "KINDLEAMZ-67578",
               "fields": {
                "summary": "contingency is displaying for confirmed card.",
                "priority": {
                    "name": "P1",
                    "id": "1"
                },
                "created": "2019-09-23T11:25:21.000+0000"
            }
        },
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id": "2019428",
            "self": "https://amazon.kindle.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/2019428",
            "key": "KINDLEAMZ-68661",
            "fields": {
                "summary": "card",
                "priority": {
                    "name": "P1",
                    "id": "1"
                },
                "created": "2019-09-23T11:25:21.000+0000"
            }
        },
        {
            "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
            "id": "2010958",
            "self": "https://amazon.kindle.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/2010958",
            "key": "KINDLEAMZ-68167",
            "fields": {
                "summary": "Test Card",
                "priority": {
                    "name": "P1",
                    "id": "1"
                },
                "created": "2019-09-23T11:25:21.000+0000"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So I just planned to restructure this payload like all the `issues[]` into as an object and write down in separate file. So that I can avoid that issue.

**Expected output:**

For that above sample data I have 4 records in `issues[].length` so I just want to create 4 different files with below format:

**File1.json:**

```
{
"key": "KINDLEAMZ-67578",
"summary": "contingency is displaying for confirmed card.",
"name": "P1",
"created": "2019-09-23T11:25:21.000+0000"
}
```

The same way I want to looping the other arrays and get the values as like above and write down in `File2.json`, `File3.json`, and `File4.json`.

Since the data is dynamic and so I just want this file creation happen based of length of `issues[]` array.

Is there anyway to achieve this by using shell script? Or any CLI library.

Please advise me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify -c/--compact-output flag to make jq put each entity on a single, separate line, then use awk to write each line to a separate file.

```
jq -c '.issues[] | {
  key,
  summary: .fields.summary,
  name:    .fields.priority.name,
  created: .fields.created
}' file | awk '{
  f = ("file" NR ".json")
  print > f
  close(f)
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk and extension gawk-json:

```
awk '
@load "json"
{
    lines=lines $0

    if(json_fromJSON(lines,data)==1){
        for(i in data["issues"]) {
            out["key"] = data["issues"][i]["key"]
            out["summary"] = data["issues"][i]["fields"]["summary"]
            out["created"] = data["issues"][i]["fields"]["created"]
            out["name"] = data["issues"][i]["fields"]["priority"]["name"]

            file="file" i ".json"
            print json_toJSON(out) > file
            close(file)
            delete out
        }
    }
}' file.json
```

Output:

```
$ cat file1.json | jq '.'                # useless use of cat but used to emphasize
{
  "created": "2019-09-23T11:25:21.000+0000",
  "key": "KINDLEAMZ-67578",
  "summary": "contingency is displaying for confirmed card.",
  "name": "P1"
}
```